# Sharing specific location on map using CartoDB?

Tags: carto

I have created a map of B&Bs/inns in the US.  I am trying to figure out how to send someone a link to the exact location on the map when I zoom in on their blue marker identifying their property.

If I click the share button provided by Carto, I am only able to link to the default zoomed out version of the map.

I would like to generate the custom URLs automatically by clicking a button and not have to do it manually.

Here is the map: http://www.innfan.com/view-map/

Answer (score 2):

You can add some extra parameters to that URL in order to specify the center coordinates and the level of zoom: http://docs.cartodb.com/faqs.html#how-can-i-set-the-position-of-an-embedded-map

For example:

```
http://<username>.cartodb.com/viz/<viz_id>/embed_map?zoom=3&center_lat=0&center_lon=0
```

From your question it's not clear if you just want to do this manually or if you would like to generate these custom URLs from a button.

In this case, I have built an example here: http://bl.ocks.org/iriberri/0c65b681afb46d4cbc31

The code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Get coordinates of geometry | CartoDB.js</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://cartodb.com/assets/favicon.ico" />
    <style>
      html, body, #map {
        height: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
      }

      body > div.cartodb-header{
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      top:0px;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
      font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,sans-serif;
      line-height: normal;
      z-index: 99999;
}


  </style> 
    </style>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/3.14/themes/css/cartodb.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>



    <!-- include cartodb.js library -->
    <script src="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/3.14/cartodb.js"></script>

    <script>
      function main() {

    var map = new L.Map('map', {
      zoomControl: false,
      center: [43, 0],
      zoom: 3

          });
    L.tileLayer('http://tile.stamen.com/toner/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      attribution: 'Stamen',
    }).addTo(map);

    embed_url = 'http://documentation.cartodb.com/viz/236085de-ea08-11e2-958c-5404a6a683d5/embed_map'

       cartodb.createLayer(map, 'http://documentation.cartodb.com/api/v2/viz/236085de-ea08-11e2-958c-5404a6a683d5/viz.json')
       .addTo(map)
       .on('done', function(layer) {

  // change the query for the first layer
  var subLayerOptions = {
      sql: "SELECT * FROM example_cartodbjs_1 where pop_other::float > 1000000",
      cartocss: "#example_cartodbjs_1{marker-fill: #109DCD; marker-width: 5; marker-line-color: white; marker-line-width: 0;}"
        }

  var sublayer = layer.getSubLayer(0);
  sublayer.set(subLayerOptions);


  sublayer.on('featureClick', function(e, latlng, pos, data) {
          alert("Hey! You clicked " + latlng +". Your URL is: " + embed_url+"?center_lat="+latlng[0]+"&center_lon="+latlng[1]+"&zoom=10");

    });
  }).on('error', function() {
        //log the error
});
      }
      window.onload = main;
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!  I edited the question to add a little clarification.

Comment: Let me try to find some time to build an example for you if nobody does it before :)

Comment: Done, hope it helps!